# How are Azure BlobStorage type accounts different from StorageV2 accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

In my Azure subscription, I have used both Storage Accounts that are of the type BlobStorage and some that say Storage or StorageV2...

I know the difference that my BlobStorage types do NOT support Tables, Files, etc containers.

But, are there other differences that I should be aware of? Is StorageV2 any faster that Blob only storage?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview?

Comment: Yeah, but often those documents leave out the nuances...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> General-purpose v2 storage accounts support the latest Azure Storage
>   features and incorporate all of the functionality of general-purpose
>   v1 and Blob storage accounts. General-purpose v2 accounts deliver the
>   lowest per-gigabyte capacity prices for Azure Storage, as well as
>   industry-competitive transaction prices.

From the description, the v2 General Storage account which takes the features of the blob storage accounts and combines then with the general storage account, plus tiering. And I think the most important to the custom is the price. Follow this [link](http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=20834), there is an exmaple analysing the difference in price of the two type storages.

Answer (score 0):

No real 'nuances', just feature differences as stated in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview), new storage you want on V2, older storage you want to migrate to V2 if possible.

Example:

**General-purpose V2**

Blob Tier: Hot, Cool, Archive

Replication: LRS, ZRS4, GRS, RA-GRS

Resource Manager

**General-purpose V1**

Blob Tier:N/A

Replication: LRS, GRS, RA-GRS

Resource Manager, Classic

Hope this help.........

Comment: also worth to mention about the cost difference